# how do can I add multiple rows after using Inner join on two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables in mysql db. The two tables are connected through a key : 
*five_day_general_information.days_dates_id = five_weekly_day_calander.id*

```
SELECT
five_weekly_day_calander.Total_working_days
FROM five_day_general_information
INNER JOIN five_weekly_day_calander
ON five_day_general_information.days_dates_id = five_weekly_day_calander.id
WHERE five_day_general_information.Pro_id = 133;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZx0M.png)

AS YOU SEE IN THE PICTURE,
How can I add the 5 and 2 and return the results which is 7 so I can use that results in php

Comment: `SELECT sum(five_weekly_day_calander.Total_working_days) FROM ...`

Comment: What do you mean by "add"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(fwdc.Total_working_days) as Total_working_days
FROM five_day_general_information fdgi JOIN
     five_weekly_day_calander fwdc
     ON fdgi.days_dates_id = fwd.id
WHERE fdgi.Pro_id = 133;
```

You can refer to the returned value as `Total_working_days` in the PHP result set.

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.